# R:Shiny - reactive output is not working within grid.arrange(from gridExtra)

Tags: r, shiny, gridextra

I'm making a summary plot with gridExtra combined with a barplot from Ggplot.

The problem is that I want to make the summary reactive to the radioButtons input.

**What I want to achieve:**

[image]

**What I have:**

[image]

I'm sure is because of the use of the "input$radio" part, that I use in my server.R:

> shiny::runApp()

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7548
Warning in grob$wrapvp <- vp : Coercing LHS to a list
Error in gList(structure(list("tbl.precio.nuevo", wrapvp = structure(list( : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

My code:

Ui.R:

```
library(shiny)


shinyUI(fluidPage(
        includeCSS("D:\\RCoursera\\r-s-l\\www\\rsl.css"),
        titlePanel("R - Tvs"),
        sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                        p("This dashboards muestra los tvs en la secciÃ³n"),
                        p("La data se obtuvo de esta secciÃ³n: \n",
                          a("R TV todas", 
                            href = "http://www")),
                        img(src="", height = 60, width = 120),
                        br(),
                        br(),
                        p("Se consideraron los siguientes atributos: marca, producto y precio")



                ),
                mainPanel(
                        tabsetPanel(
                                tabPanel("Por marca", radioButtons("radio", label = h6("Precio actual vs precio antes"),
                                                                                        choices = list("Precio actual" = "tbl.precio.nuevo", "Precio antes" = "tbl.precio.antes"),
                                                                                        selected = "tbl.precio.nuevo", inline = T), plotOutput("plot1")),
                                tabPanel("Por rango de precio", plotOutput("plot2"),
                                         dataTableOutput('mytable')),
                                tabPanel("Dif. descuento %", plotOutput("plot3"))
                        )
                )
        )
))
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(gridExtra)


setwd("D:\\RCoursera\\r-s-l")

r.tv <- read.csv("D:\\RCoursera\\R\\r-tv.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)




r.tv.cantidad <- ripley.tv  %>%
        group_by(marca) %>%
        summarise(cantidad = length(marca))




####




tbl.precio.nuevo <- tableGrob(t(prettyNum(summary(r.tv$precio.nuevo), big.mark = ",")))

tbl.precio.antes <- tableGrob(t(prettyNum(summary(r.tv$precio.antes), big.mark = ",")))





####






# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

        # Expression that generates a histogram. The expression is
        # wrapped in a call to renderPlot to indicate that:
        #
        #  1) It is "reactive" and therefore should re-execute automatically
        #     when inputs change
        #  2) Its output type is a plot




        output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
                ### GrÃ¡ficos 


                ### GrÃ¡fico 1:






               g <- ggplot(r.tv.cantidad, aes(x=marca, y= cantidad)) + 
                        geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .7, fill= "lightblue") +
                        labs(title = "",
                             x = "", y = "") +
                        geom_text(aes(label=cantidad), vjust=-0.2, size = 06)  +
                        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour="grey10",size=12,hjust=.5,vjust=.5,face="plain"),
                              axis.text.y = element_text(colour="grey10",size=12,,hjust=1,vjust=0,face="plain"),  
                              axis.title.x = element_text(colour="grey40",size=14,angle=0,hjust=.5,vjust=0,face="plain"),
                              axis.title.y = element_text(colour="grey40",size=14,angle=90,hjust=.5,vjust=.5,face="plain"),
                              plot.title = element_text(vjust=2)) +
                       scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 50))


               grid.arrange(input$radio, g,
                            nrow=2,
                            as.table=TRUE,
                            heights=c(1,3))





        })






})
```

My data:

```
r.tv <- structure(list(marca = c("SAMSUNG", "SAMSUNG", "PANASONIC", "HAIER", 
"HAIER", "HAIER", "HAIER", "HAIER", "HAIER", "HAIER", "PANASONIC", 
"HAIER", "SAMSUNG", "SAMSUNG", "SAMSUNG", "SAMSUNG", "SAMSUNG", 
"SAMSUNG", "SAMSUNG", "SAMSUNG", "SAMSUNG", "SAMSUNG", "SAMSUNG", 
"LG", "LG", "LG", "LG", "LG", "LG", "LG", "LG", "LG", "LG", "LG", 
"LG", "LG", "PANASONIC", "PANASONIC", "LG", "LG", "LG", "SONY", 
"SONY", "SONY", "SAMSUNG", "SAMSUNG", "SAMSUNG", "SAMSUNG", "SAMSUNG", 
"SAMSUNG", "SONY", "SONY", "SAMSUNG", "SAMSUNG", "LG", "LG", 
"LG", "SONY", "SAMSUNG", "AOC", "PANASONIC", "SONY", "LG", "AOC", 
"LG", "SONY", "SONY", "SONY", "SONY", "SONY", "SONY", "SHARP", 
"SHARP", "SHARP", "SAMSUNG", "LG", "LG", "LG", "LG", "SAMSUNG", 
"SONY", "LG", "LG", "LG", "LG", "LG", "PANASONIC", "SONY", "SHARP", 
"SONY", "PANASONIC", "SONY", "SAMSUNG", "AOC", "PANASONIC", "SHARP", 
"AOC"), producto = c("SAMSUNG SMART TV LED FHD 48\" 3D 48J6400", 
"SAMSUNG SMART TV LED FHD 40\" 40J5300", "PANASONIC TV LED FULL HD 40'' TC-40CS600L", 
"HAIER TELEVISOR LED LE28F6600 28\"", "HAIER SMART TV 40\" HD LE40K5000N", 
"HAIER TV LED HD 32'' LE32B7000", "HAIER SMART TV  32'' LE32K5000N", 
"HAIER TV LED FHD 55\" - LE55B8000", "HAIER TV LED LE40B8000 FULL HD 40\"", 
"HAIER TV LE24B8000 LED HD 24\" - NEGRO", "PANASONIC TV LED FULL HD 42'' TC-42AS610", 
"HAIER TELEVISOR LED LE50K5000N 50\"", "SAMSUNG SMART TV LED UHD 40\" 40JU6500", 
"SAMSUNG SMART TV ULTRA HD 48'' 48JU6500", "SAMSUNG SMART TV 50JU6500 LED UHD 50\" - NEGRO", 
"SAMSUNG SMART TV ULTRA HD 55'' 3D 55JS9000", "SAMSUNG SMART TV LED UHD 55\" 55JU6500", 
"SAMSUNG SMART TV ULTRA HD 55'' 55JU6700", "SAMSUNG SMART TV CURVO 55JU7500 LED UHD 55\" 3D - NEGRO", 
"SAMSUNG SMART TV ULTRA HD 65'' 3D 65JS9000", "SAMSUNG SMART TV 65JU6500 LED UHD 65\"", 
"SAMSUNG SMART TV ULTRA HD 65'' 65JU7500", "SAMSUNG SMART TV LED UHD 75\" 75JU6500", 
"LG SMART TV WEB OS 40\" FULL HD 40LF6350", "LG SMART TV 3D 42\" FULL HD 42LF6400", 
"LG TV LED 42\" FULL HD CINEMA 3D 42LF6450", "LG TV LED 49\" FULL HD CINEMA 3D 49LF6450", 
"LG SMART TV LF6400 49\" FULL HD 3D", "LG TV 43UF6750 43\" ULTRA HD 4K", 
"LG TV 49\" ULTRA HD 4K 49UF6750", "LG TV LED 49\" ULTRA HD SMART UF6900", 
"LG SMART TV 49UF7700 49\" ULTRA HD 4K", "LG SMART TV 49UF8500 49\" ULTRA HD 4K 3D", 
"LG TV LED 55\" CINEMA 3D SMART TV 55UF7700", "LG SMART TV 65UF7700 65\" ULTRA HD 4K", 
"LG SMART TV 55UF8500 55\" ULTRA HD 4K 3D", "PANASONIC TV LED 55\" ULTRA HD 4K SMART TC-55CX640W", 
"PANASONIC TV LED 50\" ULTRA HD 4K SMART TC-50CX640W", "LG SMART TV 70UF7700 3D ULTRA HD 70\"", 
"LG TV LED CURVO 65\" ULTRA HD 4K CINEMA SMART UG8700", "LG TV LED 60\" FULL HD SMART LF6350", 
"SONY SMART TV KDL-50FA95C 50\" FULL HD 3D", "SONY SMART TV KDL50W805C 50\" FULL HD 3D", 
"SONY TV LED 40\" FULL HD KDL-40R354B", "SAMSUNG SMART TV LED FULL HD 40'' 40J5500", 
"SAMSUNG SMART TV LED FULL HD 50'' 50J5500", "SAMSUNG TV LED HD 32'' 32JH4005", 
"SAMSUNG SMART TV LED FULL HD 50\" 50J5300", "SAMSUNG SMART TV LED 48\" FULL HD 48J5300", 
"SAMSUNG SMART TV FULL HD 40'' 3D 40J6400", "SONY TV LED 32\" HD SMART KDL-32R505C", 
"SONY TV LED 40\" SMART FULL HD KDL-40R555C - NEGRO", "SAMSUNG SMART TV LED FHD 55\" 3D 55J6400", 
"SAMSUNG TV 40JH5005 LED FHD 40\" - NEGRO", "LG TV 43\" FULL HD 43LF5410", 
"LG SMART TV 32LF585B LED HD 32\" - BLANCO", "LG TV LED 49\" FULL HD SMART 49LF5900", 
"SONY SMART TV 65\" FULL HD 3D KDL-65W855C", "SAMSUNG SMART TV LED FHD 48\" UN48J6500", 
"AOC TV LED 40\" FULL HD LE40F1551", "PANASONIC TV LED 32'' SMART HD TC-32AS600L", 
"SONY TV LED 32'' HD KDL-32R304B", "LG TV OLED 55\" SMART 3D FULL HD 55EC9300 PLATEADO", 
"AOC TV LED HD 32'' LE32W454F", "LG TV LED 58\" ULTRA HD SMART 58UF8300", 
"SONY TV LED 55\" FULL HD SMART 3D KDL-55W805C", "SONY TV LED 49\" ULTRA HD 4K XBR-49X835C", 
"SONY TV LED 55\" ULTRA HD 4K XBR-55X855C", "SONY TV LED ULTRA DELGADO 55\" ULTRA HD 4K XBR-65X905C", 
"SONY TV LED 75\" ULTRA HD 4K 3D XBR-75X945C", "SONY TV LED ULTRA DELGADO 55\" ULTRA HD 4K XBR-55X905C", 
"SHARP SMART TV LED 60'' ULTRA HD 4K LC60UE30U", "SHARP SMART TV LED 70'' ULTRA HD 4K LC70UE30U", 
"SHARP SMART TV LED 80'' ULTRA HD 4K LC80UE30U", "SAMSUNG SMART TV LED FULL HD 48'' 48J5500", 
"LG SMART TV CURVO 79UG8800 79\" ULTRA HD 4K 3D", "LG SMART TV 65UF9500 65\" ULTRA HD 4K 3D", 
"LG SMART TV 65UF8500 65\" ULTRA HD 4K 3D", "LG SMART TV 55UF9500 55\" ULTRA HD 4K 3D", 
"SAMSUNG SMART TV LED HD 32\" 32J4300", "SONY TV LED 48\" SMART FULL HD KDL-48R555C - NEGRO", 
"LG SMART TV 55UG8700 55\" ULTRA HD 4K 3D", "LG SMART TV 60UF8500 60\" ULTRA HD 4K 3D", 
"LG SMART TV 55LF6500 55\" FULL HD 3D", "LG TV 32LF550B 32\" HD", 
"LG TV LED 47\" FULL HD 47LB5610", "PANASONIC TV LED FULL HD 50'' TC-50AS600L", 
"SONY TV SMART LED 55\" UHD 3D XBR-55X855B", "SHARP TV LED FULL HD 4K LC70SQ17U 70''", 
"SONY TV LED SMART UHD 79\" XBR-79X905B", "PANASONIC TV LED FULL HD 40'' TC-40A400L", 
"SONY TV LED SMART UHD 70\" XBR-70X855B", "SAMSUNG SMART TV UHD 55'' 3D CURVO 55HU8700", 
"AOC TV FULL HD LE40D3142 40\" - NEGRO", "PANASONIC TELEVISOR LED 42\" TC-42AS650L", 
"SHARP SMART TV LCD FHD 70\" LC70LE660", "AOC TV LED FULL HD 58'' LE58D3140"
), pulgadas = c(48L, 40L, 40L, 28L, 40L, 32L, 32L, 55L, 40L, 
24L, 42L, 50L, 40L, 48L, 50L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 
75L, 40L, 42L, 42L, 49L, 49L, 43L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 55L, 65L, 
55L, 55L, 50L, 70L, 65L, 60L, 50L, 50L, 40L, 40L, 50L, 32L, 50L, 
48L, 40L, 32L, 40L, 55L, 40L, 43L, 32L, 49L, 65L, 48L, 40L, 32L, 
32L, 55L, 32L, 58L, 55L, 49L, 55L, 55L, 75L, 55L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 
48L, 79L, 65L, 65L, 55L, 32L, 48L, 55L, 60L, 55L, 32L, 47L, 50L, 
55L, 70L, 79L, 40L, 70L, 55L, 40L, 42L, 70L, 58L), precio.antes = c(2799L, 
1799L, 1699L, 599L, 1299L, 699L, 999L, 1999L, 999L, 499L, 1899L, 
1799L, 2499L, 3999L, 3699L, 10999L, 4299L, 5499L, 6999L, 14999L, 
8999L, 9999L, 14599L, 1999L, 2299L, 2299L, 2899L, 2999L, 2299L, 
23992L, 3599L, 3799L, 4799L, 4999L, 8499L, 5999L, 4999L, 3999L, 
11999L, 10999L, 4399L, 4499L, 3799L, 1399L, 2299L, 2799L, 999L, 
2199L, 2299L, 2299L, 1299L, 1699L, 3499L, 1399L, 1549L, 1299L, 
2399L, 6499L, 2999L, 999L, 1249L, 999L, 14999L, 799L, 5999L, 
4499L, 4999L, 6499L, 12999L, 24999L, 8999L, 5999L, 7599L, 14999L, 
2499L, 29999L, 13999L, 9999L, 9699L, 1299L, 2399L, 6999L, 7999L, 
3699L, 999L, 1899L, 2999L, 7999L, 8499L, 24999L, 1399L, 13999L, 
8499L, 999L, 2599L, 5799L, 2399L), precio.nuevo = c(2299, 1399, 
1299, 549, 1099, 629, 799, 1699, 849, 439, 1499, 1549, 1759.2, 
2099.3, 2309.3, 7699.3, 2799.3, 3639.3, 4899.3, 10499.3, 5109.3, 
6999.3, 10219.3, 1399, 1599, 1599, 2199, 2199, 1299, 23992, 2299, 
2299, 2899, 2999, 5999, 3899, 4999, 3999, 8999, 6999, 4099, 3999, 
3499, 1299, 1799, 2399, 799, 2199, 1799, 1999, 1199, 1599, 2999, 
1199, 1399, 1099, 1999, 5999, 2799, 999, 1199, 949, 7999, 799, 
5299, 4299, 3999, 5999, 11999, 23999, 7999, 5699, 7599, 14499, 
2399, 29999, 11999, 8999, 7499, 1099, 2199, 6599, 7099, 3599, 
899, 1599, 2199, 4999, 6499, 19999, 1399, 9999, 5999, 999, 2599, 
5699, 2399), dif.precios = c(500, 400, 400, 50, 200, 70, 200, 
300, 150, 60, 400, 250, 739.8, 1899.7, 1389.7, 3299.7, 1499.7, 
1859.7, 2099.7, 4499.7, 3889.7, 2999.7, 4379.7, 600, 700, 700, 
700, 800, 1000, 0, 1300, 1500, 1900, 2000, 2500, 2100, 0, 0, 
3000, 4000, 300, 500, 300, 100, 500, 400, 200, 0, 500, 300, 100, 
100, 500, 200, 150, 200, 400, 500, 200, 0, 50, 50, 7000, 0, 700, 
200, 1000, 500, 1000, 1000, 1000, 300, 0, 500, 100, 0, 2000, 
1000, 2200, 200, 200, 400, 900, 100, 100, 300, 800, 3000, 2000, 
5000, 0, 4000, 2500, 0, 0, 100, 0), dif.porcentual = c(17.86, 
22.23, 23.54, 8.35, 15.4, 10.01, 20.02, 15.01, 15.02, 12.02, 
21.06, 13.9, 29.6, 47.5, 37.57, 30, 34.88, 33.82, 30, 30, 43.22, 
30, 30, 30.02, 30.45, 30.45, 24.15, 26.68, 43.5, 0, 36.12, 39.48, 
39.59, 40.01, 29.42, 35.01, 0, 0, 25, 36.37, 6.82, 11.11, 7.9, 
7.15, 21.75, 14.29, 20.02, 0, 21.75, 13.05, 7.7, 5.89, 14.29, 
14.3, 9.68, 15.4, 16.67, 7.69, 6.67, 0, 4, 5.01, 46.67, 0, 11.67, 
4.45, 20, 7.69, 7.69, 4, 11.11, 5, 0, 3.33, 4, 0, 14.29, 10, 
22.68, 15.4, 8.34, 5.72, 11.25, 2.7, 10.01, 15.8, 26.68, 37.5, 
23.53, 20, 0, 28.57, 29.42, 0, 0, 1.72, 0), rangos = c("S/.1500 - S/.2500", 
"S/.500 - S/.1500", "S/.500 - S/.1500", "S/.500 - S/.1500", "S/.500 - S/.1500", 
"S/.500 - S/.1500", "S/.500 - S/.1500", "S/.1500 - S/.2500", 
"S/.500 - S/.1500", "< S/.500", "S/.500 - S/.1500", "S/.1500 - S/.2500", 
"S/.1500 - S/.2500", "S/.1500 - S/.2500", "S/.1500 - S/.2500", 
"> S/.4,500", "S/.2500 - S/.3500", "S/.3500 - S/.4500", "> S/.4,500", 
"> S/.4,500", "> S/.4,500", "> S/.4,500", "> S/.4,500", "S/.500 - S/.1500", 
"S/.1500 - S/.2500", "S/.1500 - S/.2500", "S/.1500 - S/.2500", 
"S/.1500 - S/.2500", "S/.500 - S/.1500", "> S/.4,500", "S/.1500 - S/.2500", 
"S/.1500 - S/.2500", "S/.2500 - S/.3500", "S/.2500 - S/.3500", 
"> S/.4,500", "S/.3500 - S/.4500", "> S/.4,500", "S/.3500 - S/.4500", 
"> S/.4,500", "> S/.4,500", "S/.3500 - S/.4500", "S/.3500 - S/.4500", 
"S/.2500 - S/.3500", "S/.500 - S/.1500", "S/.1500 - S/.2500", 
"S/.1500 - S/.2500", "S/.500 - S/.1500", "S/.1500 - S/.2500", 
"S/.1500 - S/.2500", "S/.1500 - S/.2500", "S/.500 - S/.1500", 
"S/.1500 - S/.2500", "S/.2500 - S/.3500", "S/.500 - S/.1500", 
"S/.500 - S/.1500", "S/.500 - S/.1500", "S/.1500 - S/.2500", 
"> S/.4,500", "S/.2500 - S/.3500", "S/.500 - S/.1500", "S/.500 - S/.1500", 
"S/.500 - S/.1500", "> S/.4,500", "S/.500 - S/.1500", "> S/.4,500", 
"S/.3500 - S/.4500", "S/.3500 - S/.4500", "> S/.4,500", "> S/.4,500", 
"> S/.4,500", "> S/.4,500", "> S/.4,500", "> S/.4,500", "> S/.4,500", 
"S/.1500 - S/.2500", "> S/.4,500", "> S/.4,500", "> S/.4,500", 
"> S/.4,500", "S/.500 - S/.1500", "S/.1500 - S/.2500", "> S/.4,500", 
"> S/.4,500", "S/.3500 - S/.4500", "S/.500 - S/.1500", "S/.1500 - S/.2500", 
"S/.1500 - S/.2500", "> S/.4,500", "> S/.4,500", "> S/.4,500", 
"S/.500 - S/.1500", "> S/.4,500", "> S/.4,500", "S/.500 - S/.1500", 
"S/.2500 - S/.3500", "> S/.4,500", "S/.1500 - S/.2500")), .Names = c("marca", 
"producto", "pulgadas", "precio.antes", "precio.nuevo", "dif.precios", 
"dif.porcentual", "rangos"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-97L))
```

Comment: seems related to this: https://github.com/baptiste/gridextra/wiki#problems-with-shiny

Comment: @baptiste, thanks so muhc for gridExtra. Would you mind making a complete answer? I don't get how to apply your workaround within my shinyapp.

Comment: i don't use Shiny, so it's hard for me to tell what the code is doing; I was only offering this pointer in case it was related, but it may not be

Comment: though, looking at the comment about return value being a plot, I imagine it's not expecting the output (and side-effect) of `grid.arrange()`

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and this works:

```
# add after g
gg <- ggplotGrob(g)
if(input$radio=="tbl.precio.nuevo"){
    g1 <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(gg, grobs = tbl.precio.nuevo 
                              ,t=6, l=6, b=5, r=2
                              )
} else {
    g1 <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(gg, grobs = tbl.precio.antes 
                                  ,t=6, l=6, b=5, r=2
    )
}
grid::grid.draw(g1)
```

All files in: [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/ferroao/stacktest)